# Random Number adding issue

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, random

Hi I created this code but now I am stuck.
How do I add all the numbers between N1 and N2 except the ones divisible by 5?
And display the result?

Problem: My `if` statement if y is divisible by 5 do not add, only add numbers that are not divisible by 5. I don't know how to do that.

New code how about this?

```
                        Console.Write("Enter N1 : ");
                        int N1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Enter N2: ");
                        int N2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        int counter = 1;
                        while ()
                        {
                            Console.Write("");
                            counter++;
                        }
```

Comment: What exception? On which line? We don't like guessing...

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek My if statment if y is divisible by 5 do not add only add numbers that not divisible by 5 I dont know how to do that.

Comment: Oh, so it's just *my **except** condition is not working*, not *the code is throwing an exception*... You should be more precise.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here? Are you trying to output all numbers between (including or excluding N1 and N2?) N1 and N2 except numbers divisible by five or do you want a random output between these values and doing something special when it's divisible by five?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek For ex: I put N1:1 N2:10 so it will add very number between 1-10 except 5.

Comment: If the idea is to add every number between X and Y why are you using `Random`?! You're question is really confusing.

Comment: @noMad17 I want it to ignore numbers divisible by 5 and add all the rest together.

Comment: @TheBoringGuy, right now you're randomizing a number between 1-10 excluding 10 and only doing this 5 times.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Oh I just notice I used random lol is there a way to display number from N1 to N2 without random? I am still new to this sorry.

Comment: nvm got it solved LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I add all the numbers between N1 and N2 except the ones divisible by 5?

If the idea is to add every number between N1 and N2 why are you using Random?! You're question is really confusing.

```
Console.WriteLine("N1: ");
int N1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("N2: ");
int N2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int sum = 0;
for (int X = N1; X <= N2; X++)
{
    if (X % 5 != 0)
    {
        sum += X;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}", sum.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You should check this condition? IF (N1 > N2)

Comment: @IJ Loop condition will check it for me. And if that's true, `sum` will be the default `0`, because loop body won't be executed at all.

Comment: So he will get '0' for addition of numbers between 30 and 20 except the ones divisible by 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

The loop is going to run only five turn. How can it add all numbers in range n1 and n2 though?

Use this logic:

```
int  sum=0;
for(int i=N1;i<=N2;i++)
{
    if ( !(i%5 == 0))
        sum=sum+i;

}
console.writeline(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: use tryParse to avoid invalid input exceptions and rest thing are as

Here if user enters input as n1 is small and n2 is greater or vice versa, both are handled:

```
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("N1: ");
        int N1 = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out N1);
        Console.WriteLine("N2: ");
        int N2 = 0;
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out N2);
        int x1 = 0, x2 = 0;
        if (N1 < N2)
        {
            x1 = N1;
            x2 = N2;
        }
        else
        {
            x1 = N2;
            x2 = N1;
        }
            for (int X = x1; X <= x2; X++)
            {
                int y = rnd.Next(N1, N2);
                if (y % 5 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
                else
                {
                    total = total + y;
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`rnd.Next(N1, N2);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns a random integer that is within a specified range.

Try this, you don't need the `else` condition. Just check if it is not divisible by 5, and add it to totalSum:

```
int totalSum = 0;
for (int x = N1; x <= N2; x++)
{
    int y = rnd.Next(N1, N2);
    if (y % 5 != 0)
    {
        totalSum += y;
    }
}
```